# Getting the id of a div which is being displayed

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div id="skills">
    <div class="items" id="items1" style="display:none">1</div>
    <div class="items" id="items2" >2</div>
    <div class="items" id="items3" style="display:none">3</div>
    <div class="items" id="items4" style="display:none">4</div>
    <div class="items" id="items5" style="display:none">5</div>
</div>
```

I need to access the `div` which is being displayed and get it's `id`.
Please let me know how can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.not()` which remove the elements from the set of matched elements.

```
var divId = $("div.items").not(":hidden").prop("id");
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly9251a9/)

Comment: What is the difference between using 'attr' and 'prop' at the end.

Comment: And Thanks All . All answers are useful and added to my learning

Comment: The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes. Read more, https://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: I would say that matching the negative reduces the readability. The actual desired elements are the "visible" ones and while searching for the "not hidden" would yield the same results I still feel it's slightly awkward to think about the selectors like this.

Comment: Ahh... of course - what's bothering me here is that the code is implicit and not explicit. Matching "not hidden" *means* to match "visible" implicitly. Matching using `:visible` would be the explicit form of that selector.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `:visible` selector:

```
var visibleId = $('.items:visible').prop('id'); // = 'items2'
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has a dedicated `:visible` selector. You can use this to match any element that is being displayed.

https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

> Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document. Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.
>
> Elements with `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0` are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout.

So to use this in your scenario, you would have something like this:

```
var desired_id = $('.items:visible').prop('id');
```

**Keep in mind** that if more than one element is matched using `.items:visible`, you will only get the first matched element's `id` and not all of them.